# Indicator to indicate vibration on the phone

Tags: android

Currently I am developing a app which would vibrate morse code.

I am using this code to vibrate the pattern:

```
int dot = 100;
int dash = 220;
int short_gap = 200;
int medium_gap = 700;
s = new long[] {0, dot, short_gap, dash, medium_gap}
Vibrator vibrator;
vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);       
vibrator.vibrate(s, -1);
```

How do I add an indicator to indicate if my application is vibrating a dot or a dash?

I know I can use a for loop to transverse the `long[]` and then use a if else statement to change a textview background colour to indicate a change in the pattern. But how do I get the for loop to keep within the vibration ms for each change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dot = new long[] {200, 100};
dash = new long[] {700, 220};
String s = "01";
for (int i = s.length() - 1, i >= 0, i--) {
  if (s.charAt(i) == "0") {
    // CHANGE TEXTVIEW HERE
    vibrator.vibrate(dot, -1);
  }
  else {
    vibrator.vibrate(dash, -1);
  }
}
```

Because it takes a few mil-seconds to execute the code before `vibrate` and to start the vibrator, you may need to shorten the time accordingly if you want to be accurate.

---

By the way, according to the [api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate%28long%5B%5D,%20int%29), your original code should be

```
s = new long[] { short_gap, dot, medium_gap, dash}
```

Comment: yep u are right.. my original code starts with a 0,dot,short_gap,dash,medium_gap.  i will try to see if i can modify ur code in as my classifier is made up to 36 characters and i use a System.coppyarray to put each of them into a very long array depending on how many character is the text

Comment: ur solution is a working one at least from ur code but i need something that i can adapt into my codes i will give it a try :)

Comment: @benjamin lee, do you have to use `long[]` to present all your codes?

Comment: yes i do, i got an idea from ur solution :) will be asking another qn thanks!